# Error while calling secured webservice from Mule Project

Tags: mule, esb

Need to call a secured web service from one of my Mule Project.For that I have created a self signed certificate and configured my projects follows:

1)Keep the keystore.jks inside the resource folder of my Project

2)Defined a https connector in the Globals.xml file

```
<https:connector name="movilcashHttpsConnector" doc:name="HTTP-HTTPS" clientSoTimeout="10000" cookieSpec="netscape" receiveBacklog="0" receiveBufferSize="0" sendBufferSize="0" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" validateConnections="true">
      <https:tls-key-store path="keystore.jks" keyPassword="changeit" storePassword="changeit" />
      <https:tls-server path="keystore.jks" storePassword="changeit" />
</https:connector>
```

3) While calling the https endpoint I have used the following configuration

```
    <https:outbound-endpoint method="POST"
        doc:name="HTTP" exchange-pattern="request-response" transformer-refs="Message_Properties2"
        responseTimeout="90000"
        address="https://partners.masmovilcash.com/TelepinWeb/TpinBulkLoading?BatchType=7&amp;FileExt=PNG&amp;FileAbbrv=C_R&amp;FileType=KYC_Documents&amp;CustomerID=#[flowVars['tpin-customerid']]&amp;FileSequence=2"
        connector-ref="movilcashHttpsConnector">
    </https:outbound-endpoint>
```

4)Deployed the project in a Linux server where mule standlaone is running.

But unfortunately each and every time I am getting the following error:
Message               : Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=https://partners.masmovilcash.com/TelepinWeb/JSON-RPC, connector=HttpsConnector

Message payload is of type: PostMethod (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found
            at sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator.buildTrustedChain(SimpleValidator.java:384)

---

Am I missing something?Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to perform an HTTPS request to an external service (https://partners.masmovilcash.com/TelepinWeb/JSON-RPC) what you need to make sure is that your application trusts the service certificate. That means that if you set a trust store for your HTTPS connector, said trust store needs to contain the service certificate.

Considering I've been able to access the service you need from my browser, it's probably signed by a proper certificate authority (CA) which means the default Java trust store should work. That means, try not setting any trust store/key store data so that the JVM defaults are used instead. Something like:

```
<https:connector name="movilcashHttpsConnector" doc:name="HTTP-HTTPS" clientSoTimeout="10000" cookieSpec="netscape" receiveBacklog="0" receiveBufferSize="0" sendBufferSize="0" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" validateConnections="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.After modifying the connector config Iam getting the following error: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: Seems like the default JVM trust store does not have the CA cert. I think the CA is GoDaddy so might want to check that. I think the latest updates have the certificate so you might want to try updating Java. There some data here: http://tozny.com/blog/godaddys-ssl-certs-dont-work-in-java-the-right-solution/.